# How to create a generic method to create an instance of class at n depth level?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a generic method(**NewIfNull**) to create an instance of class if object is null. But currently I am supplying the property name as hard-coded which I don't want to do. Please help if there is any way to do this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  RnD rnD = new RnD();
  rnD.NewIfNull("A").A.NewIfNull("B").B.NewIfNull("C");
  if(rnD.A.B.C != null)
  {

  }
}

class RnD
{
  public A A { get; set; }
}
class A 
{ 
  public B B { get; set; } 
}
class B 
{ 
  public C C { get; set; }
}
class C 
{    
}

public static class ExtensionClass1
{
     public static T NewIfNull<T>(this T obj, string propName)
     {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName) != null && 
           obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj) == null)
            {
                Type type =                 
                        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).PropertyType;
                if (type.IsClass)
                {
                    var getobj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, 
                       getobj);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
     }
  }
```

I don't want to pass "A", "B" and "C" as hard-coded in below code.
rnD.NewIfNull("A").A.NewIfNull("B").B.NewIfNull("C");

Comment: *"I don't want to pass "A", "B" and "C" as hard-coded in below code. "* - what *do* you want to pass then?

Comment: It would help to see what you wanted to do, instead of just what you don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer without trying to understand what you are actually trying to do is to use `nameof`:

```
rnD.NewIfNull(nameof(RnD.A)).A.NewIfNull(nameof(A.B)).B.NewIfNull(nameof(B.C));
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful!! Is there any way to pass whole path at same time like this - rnD.NewIfNull(nameof(rnD.A.B.C)); This help me to optimized the code.

Comment: no nameof just returns the name of the property as a string.

Comment: canton7 has provided a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions to do this.

```
public static TProperty NewIfNull<TObj, TProperty>(this TObj obj, Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>> selector)
{
    if (!(selector.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        || !(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected a lambda in the form x => x.Property", nameof(selector));
    }

    var property = (TProperty)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
    if (property == null)
    {
        // We already know that typeof(TProperty).IsClass is true - if it
        // wasn't, then 'property' could not have been null above.
        property = (TProperty)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TProperty));
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, property);
    }

    return property;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
rnD.NewIfNull(x => x.A).NewIfNull(x => x.B).NewIfNull(x => x.C);
```

---

You can quite easily modify it to initialise all of your properties at the same time:

```
public static void NewIfNull<TObj, TProperty>(this TObj obj, Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>> selector)
{
    object subject = obj;
    foreach (var member in GetMembers().Reverse())
    {
        if (!(member.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Member was not a property", nameof(selector));
        }

        var property = propertyInfo.GetValue(subject);
        if (property == null)
        {
            property = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(subject, property);
        }
        subject = property;
    }

    IEnumerable<MemberExpression> GetMembers()
    {
        for (var member = GetMember(selector.Body); member != null; member = GetMember(member.Expression))
        {
            yield return member;
        }
    }

    MemberExpression GetMember(Expression expr)
    {
        if (expr is ParameterExpression)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (expr is MemberExpression member)
        {
            return member;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected a lambda in the form x => x.A.B.C", nameof(selector));
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
rnD.NewIfNull(x => x.A.B.C);
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful!!

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, please upvote it. Please consider accepting the most helpful answer.